# Mezzanine filebrowser deploy

Tags: django, deployment, file-browser, mezzanine

I have installed mezzanine and I have tried to use the admin interface to upload some pictures to media library. I didn't have any problem on dev server (localhost) but on the deployment server I get the following:

```
NetworkError: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR - http://mydomain/asset_proxy/?u=http://mydomain/static/filebrowser/uploadify/uploadify.swf
```

I've tried to find a solution on the internet without any success. All the topics related to this problem are ambiguous and didn't help me at all.

It seems there might be a security issue when the server tries to load the flash object (uploadify.swf) but I don't really get it.

I'd be very happy to understand where the problem comes from as much as how to fix it.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: An error 500 means there's an error on the webserver. There is no problem (security/flash/whatever) in your browser. So... that asset_proxy thingy, does it log errors somewhere? That's where the error happens. (But also check whether the error is in Django or in any webserver (apache/nginx) that you may have in front of it).

Comment: the webserver is running in mod_apache. Of course I have checked the error logs before asking but there is no additional message, just "error". Here is another thread on this subject: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mezzanine-users/JZ6z6O-VOqs. Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: mod_apache? Do you mean mod_wsgi or mod_python? (mod_python isn't supported anymore, btw).

Comment: The mezzanine-users thread you mentioned was my first instinct. Note the conversation there was specific to nginx configuration, which is the preferred way to deploy Mezzanine. http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/deployment.html

Answer (score 1):

If anyone runs into this problem in the future, it looks like the webserver does not automatically have permissions to write to the media directory in your mezzanine project.

You can simply do something like:

`chmod -R 777 /YOUR_PROJECT/static/media`

That should clear up your issue.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I had this problem long ago and I don't remember how did I fix it. Indeed I had some permissions issue at some point but I'm not sure if that was the root of this issue.